# Publishing to the Facebook Graph API returns a strange response object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook JS SDK to publish to the GRAPH API, and while my post publishes successfully, it returns a strange response object that gets caught by the jQuery .error chain. Here's my code:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("https://graph.facebook.com/"+sbFacebook.authentication.userID+"/feed", 
      { 
        'message' : $("#question-text").val(),
        'access_token' : sbFacebook.authentication.accessToken
      }).success(
      function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      })
.error(function(response) { 
          alert(response); 
})
```

The response object looks like this:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/964/screenshotfrom201302222.png

Anyone have any idea what's going on and why it's getting caught by the error() function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you should use [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Don't forget to [initialize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) the JS SDK:

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that was dumb of me, I didn't even look at the sdk calls.